# Не работает скрипт связанный с двумя инпутами, кнопкой и таблицей

Tags: javascript, jquery

У меня возникла проблема: когда я хочу изменить цвета в таблице при помощи скрипта, двух инпутов и кнопки, у меня ни черта не работает
Что я хочу сделать: когда человек выбирает цвета инпутов, то при нажатию на кнопку скрипт должен искать элементы с таким же теле

```js
const from = $("#from");
const to = $("#to")
$("#btn").on("click", function() {
  $(`td[style="background: ${from.val()}"]`).css("background", to.val())
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="color" id="from">
<input type="color" id="to">
<input type="button" id="btn" value="change">
<table>
  <tbody>
   <tr>
     <td style="background: #f00;">1</td>
     <td>2</td>
     <td>3</td>
   </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

В чем проблема не понимаю, объясните, пожалуйста!

Comment: `from` - это ключевое слово, его нельзя использовать для названия переменных или функций. `from` используется вместе с `import`: `import foo from './bar.js'`.

Comment: @ΝNL993 - ```from``` -  не ключевое слово

Comment: @ΝNL993 - если использовать from в связке с import, то да. А так - нет. Сам проверил в VSCode

Comment: @DKorjey интересно работает конечно JavaScript...

Comment: 1) Цвет нужно указывать не в сокращенной форме. 2) Стиль нужно указать всем элементам, участвующим в поиске. 3) `style="...` подразумевает точное соответствие, а значит надо добавить точку с запятой в конце (или убрать ее у элементов).

Comment: @LaukhinAndrey 1) самое страшное в том, что даже не в сокращенной форме не работает. 2) Что ты под этим подразумеваешь? 3) Попробовать стоит

Comment: @DKorjey Само собой, ведь поиск по значению атрибута, а Вы прописываете CSS-свойство.

Comment: _"2) Что ты под этим подразумеваешь?"_ - атрибут style должен быть задан у всех элементов.
Комментарием выше я хотел сказать, что нужно использовать метод `attr()`, а не `css()`

Comment: @LaukhinAndrey, спасибо вам большое! Мне помогло ваше решение, я бы с удовольствием принял ваш ответ, но не могу, так как вы ответили в комментариях. Но все равно огромное спасибо